# Код сортирует не так, как надо

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал код, который на вход принимает ссылки и должен вывести названия фильмов, которые содержатся в обоих HTML кодах сайтов. Все работает, но почему-то нет сортировки по алфавиту в названии. Как можно исправить?

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(links):
    best_films = []

    for link in links:

        response = requests.get(link)
        response.encoding = 'utf-8'
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        all_films = soup.find_all('tr')

        for film in all_films:
            one_film = film.find_all('td')
            for _ in one_film:
                name_film = one_film[0].text
                rate_film = int(one_film[3].text)
                best_films.append((name_film, rate_film))

        best_films.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        print(best_films[0][0])
        best_films.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    link_list = []
    while 1 == 1:
        some_link = input()
        if some_link.lower() == 'конец':
            break
        link_list.append(some_link)
    main(link_list)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Название фильма</th>
            <th>Режиссёр</th>
            <th>Актёрский состав</th>
            <th>Рейтинг фильма</th>
            <th>Год</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Седьмая печать</td>
            <td>Ингмар Бергман</td>
            <td>Макс фон Сюдов, Гуннар Бьёрнстранд, Биби Андерссон</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1957</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Остров проклятых</td>
            <td>Мартин Скорсезе</td>
            <td>Леонардо Ди Каприо, Марк Руффало, Бен Кингсли, Эмили Мортимер</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>2010</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Земляничная поляна</td>
            <td>Ингмар Бергман</td>
            <td>Виктор Шёстрём, Ингрид Тулин, Биби Андерссон</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1957</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Час волка</td>
            <td>Ингмар Бергман</td>
            <td>Макс фон Сюдов, Лив Ульман, Ингрид Тулин</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1968</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Название фильма</th>
            <th>Режиссёр</th>
            <th>Актёрский состав</th>
            <th>Рейтинг фильма</th>
            <th>Год</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Земляничная поляна</td>
            <td>Ингмар Бергман</td>
            <td>Виктор Шёстрём, Ингрид Тулин, Биби Андерссон</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1957</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Фанни и Александр</td>
            <td>Ингмар Бергман</td>
            <td>Ева Фрёлинг, Бертил Гуве, Пернилла Альвин</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1982</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Седьмая печать</td>
            <td>Ингмар Бергман</td>
            <td>Макс фон Сюдов, Гуннар Бьёрнстранд, Биби Андерссон</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1957</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можете предоставить ссылки, которые вы указывали?

Comment: @arnold эти ссылки не открываются, могу скинуть html код с них

Comment: @arnold Добавил 2 кода

Comment: Попробуем разобраться

Comment: когда вы указываете URL в консоли, вы вводите путь к HTML-файлу?

Comment: Да, подается путь к HTML файлу.  вот пример http://127.0.0.1/python-as-foreign/tasks/movies/example.html

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135049/discussion-between-sd1g-and-arnold).

Comment: У вас сортировка по rate_film, а если хотите по названию, то надо sort(key=lambda x: x[0]

Comment: @Сергей в этой строке? best_films.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True), если да, то я так пробовал и не сработало. вместо того, чтобы выводить 2 названия, выводится только одно, но 2 раза

Answer (score -1):

Тогда так, лучший фильм на каждом сайте заносите еще в один список и сортируете его после завершения сканирования всех сайтов

```
        best_films.sort(key=lambda x: x[1],  
                       reverse=True)
        f.append(best_films[0][0])
        best_films.clear()
    f.sort()
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста оформить как код или вставить в мой код?